# How to test WinRT MediaCapture API by testrunner

Tags: unit-testing, windows-store-apps, webcam

Windows store application requires special user input while first accessing certain devices, like webcam, microphone, etc. In Visual studio integrated test runner, or resharper's one there is no such permission request window appeared. So test that use webcam will eventually hang forever in call to InitializeAsync():

```
[TestClass]
public class WhenRecordVideo 
{
    [UITestMethod]
    public void test1()
    {
        var captureSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
             AudioDeviceId = "",
             VideoDeviceId = deviceId.Id,
             StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
             PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Auto
        };


        var capture = new MediaCapture();
        capture.InitializeAsync(captureSettings).AsTask.Wait()
    }
```

Since test are running only on development machines is there any way to disable that permission request window, using registry/config hacks?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be testing `MediaCapture` in your tests. Microsoft would have taken care of that themselves. If you want to unit test code that you write - abstract out the photo capture code as a service and use a mock implementation of that service in your tests so you can provide deterministic images to test your own code.

Comment: Thanks, you are right isolating code from MediaCapture is a way to unittest, moreover i've already done that. However that won't solve my task fully, since i cannot check that my calls to MediaCapture are correct in terms of microsoft specs(device id is valid for example), in my unittest i can expect null references everywhere and test will pass. So that is why I'm writing also integration test using Microsoft frameworks for that. CodedUI tests seems a way to test UI since they are dealing with controls stuff, not sure whether that will work with permission's question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a better answer for you. Maybe some framework that can control mouse cursor and keyboard would be able to do that. Or some automation code (less likely). I still don't think you should be testing that and your tests won't find more than the compiler or a smoke test wouldn't find.